Choosen plugin not working with dynamic created rows in html table
I am trying to filter drop down list with the help of choosen plug in, its working fine for first row. But when I clone or dynamically create more row, then drop down list become inactive and and displaying selected value of first row in all new dynamic rows. Below is the my code . I needed guidance to resolve this issue
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Medicine Re-Location Form</title>    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script> 
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css">
  
</head>
  <body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <h3 div class="card-header" style="background-color: #3fbbc0;">Request Form</h3>
    <div class="card-body">
    <form method="POST" action="invoice.php">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead class="table-success" style="background-color: #3fbbc0;">
                    <tr>                       
                        <th width="15%"><center>Product</th>                       
            <th width="10%"><center>Qty (No)</th>                   
            <th width="20%"><center>Remarks</th>
            <th width="5%"></th>                                               
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="BtnAdd()">Add Item</button>                         
                        </th>
</tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="TBody">
                      <tr id="TRow" >
<td><Select  class="scode form-control text-end" name="scode[]" id = "scode"  class="form-control"  required onchange="GetDetail(this.closest('tr'))">
<option value="">Select Product</option>
    <?php
    include('db.php');
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM procd2");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['pro1'].'">'.$row['pro1'].'</option>';
    } ?></select>
</td>       
        <td><input type="text" class="qty form-control text-end" name="qty[]" id="ccc" pattern="\d+"></td>    
      
           <td><input type="text" class="form-control text-end" name="remarks3[]"  id="zzz" ></td>
        <td class="NoPrint"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  style="line-height: 1;" onclick="BtnDel(this)">x</button></td>
            
                      </tr>   </tbody> </table>


**<script>

jQuery('.scode').chosen();
</script>**


 <div class="col-lg-4"> <div class="form-group"><center>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"  class="btn btn-success submit_btn invoice-save-btm">     
    

</form> 

updated javascript code

<script type="text/javascript">

function GetPrint()
{
    /*For Print*/
    window.print();
}

function BtnAdd()
{
    /*Add Button*/
    var v = $("#TRow").clone().appendTo("#TBody") ;
    $(v).find("input").val('');
$(v).find("select.scode").chosen();
   
    $(v).removeClass("d-none");
    $(v).find("th").first().html($('#TBody tr').length - 1);
}

function BtnDel(v)
{
    /*Delete Button*/
       $(v).parent().parent().remove(); 
       GetTotal();

        $("#TBody").find("tr").each(
        function(index)
        {
           $(this).find("th").first().html(index);
        }

       );
}



function Calc(v)
{
    /*Detail Calculation Each Row*/
    var index = $(v).parent().parent().index();
    
    var qqq1 = document.getElementsByName("qty[]")[index].value;




    GetTotal();
}

function GetTotal()
{

    /*Footer Calculation*/   

    var sum=0;
    var amts =  document.getElementsByName("tot4[]");

    for (let index = 0; index < amts.length; index++)
    {
        var tot4 = amts[index].value;
        sum = +(sum) +  +(tot4) ; 
    }

    document.getElementById("totbil").value = sum;

    var gst =  document.getElementById("adv11").value;
    var net = +(sum) - +(gst);
    document.getElementById("netpayable1").value = net;

    

}
</script>
  


You need to initialise chosen on the new elements after creating them.  You do this at startup with jQuery('.scode').chosen(); so need to add equivalent code after updating the DOM - you already do this with .autocomplete({, so just need to add chosen in the same place

can u explain with little example ?

Using your code : $(v).find("select.scode").chosen()

@fdomn-m  I added and updated my javascript code on above question, but still not working
